# Mongoid persistance problems with a 1 to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following model:

```
class Bill
 . . . some fields . . .
belongs_to :sponsor, :class_name => "Legislator"
end
class Legislator
  .. .some fields . . .
  has_many :bills
end
```

I get this strange behavior, but I am sure this is something simple:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)
b = Bill.first
l = Legislator.first
l.bills << b
l.save
=> true
(I can view l.bills, but l.bills.all.to_a.count is 0)
 l.govtrack_id
=> 400001
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > Legislator.where(govtrack_id: 400001).first.bills
 => []
```

So I can create the association and view it. The save is successful, but when I retrieve the object, the association is gone . . . no errors. I'm confused, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `inverse_of` on your `Legislator` model. I ran a quick test (to make sure there wasn't a Mongoid issue). My models were thus:

```
class Bill
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name
  belongs_to :sponsor, :class_name => "Legislator"
end

class Legislator
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :govtrack_id
  has_many :bills, :inverse_of => :sponsor
end
```

And console output from the test:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > Bill.create(:name => "A new bill")
  => #<Bill _id: 4e0822636a4f1d11c1000001, _type: nil, created_at: 2011-06-27 06:25:39 UTC, updated_at: 2011-06-27 06:25:39 UTC, name: "A new bill", sponsor_id: nil>
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > Legislator.create(:govtrack_id => "400123")
  => #<Legislator _id: 4e0822786a4f1d11c1000002, _type: nil, created_at: 2011-06-27 06:26:00 UTC, updated_at: 2011-06-27 06:26:00 UTC, govtrack_id: "400123">
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > l = Legislator.first
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > l.bills << Bill.first
  => [#<Bill _id: 4e0822636a4f1d11c1000001, _type: nil, created_at: 2011-06-27 06:25:39 UTC, updated_at: 2011-06-27 06:26:08 UTC, name: "A new bill", sponsor_id: BSON::ObjectId('4e0822786a4f1d11c1000002')>] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > l.save!
  => true
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > Bill.first.sponsor.govtrack_id
  => "400123"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > Legislator.first.bills
 => [#<Bill _id: 4e0822636a4f1d11c1000001, _type: nil, created_at: 2011-06-27 06:25:39 UTC, updated_at: 2011-06-27 06:26:08 UTC, name: "A new bill", sponsor_id: BSON::ObjectId('4e0822786a4f1d11c1000002')>]
```

Comment: excellent. exactly what i needed. I read through the docs I could find, do you have a link to documentation on :inverse_of?

Comment: The Mongoid docs look great, but some things are definitely hard to find! :) There is a brief reference to it at the bottom of [this page](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations.html).